# Passing radio selection Array variable through session using PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html, arrays, radio-button, session-variables

- List item

I have been working on this for a few days and I can't seem to get it. I am creating an Internet airline database, unfortunately I am not very familiar with PHP/HTML but I am learning.

Right now when I try to call my session on the next page after the radio button is selected I get index errors and I can not seem to figure them out. The SQL pull works fine and all the data is displayed

Sorry if the styling is not the best. I am deleting and adding so much I lost my styling and need to fix it.

Here is the table and radio button for one of the selections I am passing

```
Session_start();

<form method="post" action="quantity.php">
                                            <?php
        for ($j=0; $j<$num_rows; $j++) 
        {

            echo "<table border='6'>
            <tr>
            <th>Select Flight</th>
            <th>Flight ID</th>
            <th>Flight Number</th>
            <th>Departure Date</th>
            <th>Flight Time</th>
            <th>Destination</th>
            <th>Origin</th>
            <th>Flight Class</th>
            <th>Flight Cost</th>
            </tr>";

            $row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($return);

            echo "<td>". "<input type='radio' name= 'Returns'         
            value=".$row2['fid'].")>". 
            "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row2['fid']. "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row2['fnumber']. "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row2['fdate']. "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row2['ftime']."</td>".  
            "<td>". $rowO['0']. ','. $rowO['1']. "</td>".
            "<td>". $rowD['0']. ','. $rowD['1']. "</td>". 
            "<td>". $row2['class']. "</td>". 
            "<td>". '$'.$row2['price']."</td>"; 

            print "<br>";

            //$_SESSION['Return']=$_POST['Returns'];
        }
            if (isset($_POST['Returns']))
            {
                 $_SESSION['Returns']=$_POST[$row2('fid')];
            }
?>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reserve" />
    </form>
```

On my next page, quantity.php, I call the variable stored in session:

```
session_start();

echo $_SESSION['Returns'];
```

All I really need to pass is the 'fid' value as I can use that later to just pull everything else from the database.

Whenever I do try and pass I can sometimes get Array(0') as the answer...

I have also tried declaring fid as a variable and then setting the name of the radio button to that variable but it would always pass the last row no matter what was checked. It would no loop through correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have searched here and dream in code as well as a friends PHP book for an answer. Unfortunately I can't find a solution that will help me or I am not implementing it correctly.

Thank you.

Comment: The syntax is `session_start();` and not `Session_start();` Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yeah, sorry I don't have it capital in my file. I typed that instead of copy paste. And I will add the error reporting. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code which is handling the post is never called.
If the form is submitted the browser will switch to "quantity.php" and doesn't call the file which contains your code.

In most cases the form action stays at the form.php.
there are you handle the post, validating the inputs and if everything is fine, you redirect the browser to the next pages.

Edit:
I just saw the this code

```
if (isset($_POST['Returns']))
            {
                 $_SESSION['Returns']=$_POST[$row2('fid')];
            }
```

is outside your loop. in this case $row2 doen't contain a valid value. This is a single variable `$_SESSION['Returns']`, maybe you need to place a array here `$_SESSION['Returns'][$row2('fid')]`. Ofcurse move it into that loop.

Comment: I included only partial code as the full code is hundreds of lines. The radio button call is all inside of a larger loop with the POST return inside of the loop and the form on the outside of it. It should be called, shouldn't it? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I sound's to me that you really need to improve you source structure to get a clean and easy to maintain code. First you should seperate php-code (logic) from html (display). this is normal done by using a template engine like smarty (http://smarty.net) or also php.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "<td>". "<input type='radio' name= 'Returns[]'         
        value=".$row2['fid'].")>".
```

or

```
 echo "<td>". "<input type='radio' name= 'Returns[".$j."]'         
        value=".$row2['fid'].")>".
```